# Mutate a dynamic subset of variable

Tags: r, dplyr

```
a = tibble(x = runif(1000,0,10),
           t = rpois(1000,4)
) %>% arrange(t)
```

I want a column `l` that averages the subset of `x` for the values associated to a `t < t(x)`.

Expected result:

for `x[t=0]`, `l = NaN`

for `x[t=1]`, `l = mean(x[t<1])`

for `x[t=2]`, `l = mean(x[t<2])`

etc.

A code that does not work:

```
a %>%
  mutate(
  l = mean(x[a$t < .$t])
  ) -> a
```

Now this could would work:

```
for (i in c(1:1000)) {
  a$l[i] = mean(a$x[a$t < a$t[i]])
}
```

But is not a `mutate`. I'd like a `mutate` so I can apply it to groups etc.

To understand better the issue: imagine that you have to average all the `x` before a date. Now: this, dynamically, in a mutate.

I think that `purrr` may be necessary but I hate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` with `mutate`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

f <- function(lim) mean(a$x[a$t < lim])

a %>% mutate(l = map_dbl(t, f))
```

Testing against OP solution:

```r
res <- a %>% mutate(l = map_dbl(t, f))
       
l <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 1000)     
for (i in c(1:1000)) l[i] = mean(a$x[a$t < a$t[i]])

assertthat::are_equal(res$l, l) # TRUE
```

Comment: I am making this Mutate(map) run on a grouped tibble with 1.5 millions of rows, and 600k groups. It is still running after 8 hrs. 

Is this normal? I think that one issue is that in my tibble, the t vector is made of dates.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me, under the hood `map` is just `apply`, and under that is just a loop.  R really slows down when it has to keep that many operations in memory, even to the point where it can just crash altogether.  You might look into multiprocessing with [`multidplyr`](https://multidplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/multidplyr.html).

Comment: You might try out a test with a small random sample, more like 10K rows than 1.5M, and see if that completes in reasonable time.  If so then you can be more confident it's the size of the data that is causing the issue.

Comment: For these kind of tasks, I am always worried about choosing `map` over `for`. It is shown that `map` is faster than `for`, but with `for` you can stop a vector operation and start after, from where you stopped.
In a sense, with `for' you always know how time is left just by printing the index...
12 hrs and still running...

Comment: It ended. While the `map` works correctly on its own, it does not accounts for `groups`. While this was not in the explicit question, now I am curious to know hot to make a `map` to recognize tibbles as `grouped`.

Comment: there is a `group_map` - consider opening a new question, i'm sure i or someone else can help.

Answer (score 1):

For each `t` value you can calculate average value of `x` and then calculate lag value of cumulative mean.

```
library(dplyr)

a %>%
  group_by(t) %>%
  summarise(l = mean(x)) %>%
  mutate(l = lag(cummean(l)))

#       t     l
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     0 NA   
# 2     1  5.33
# 3     2  5.45
# 4     3  5.36
# 5     4  5.26
# 6     5  5.16
# 7     6  5.10
# 8     7  5.07
# 9     8  5.12
#10     9  4.96
#11    10  4.98
#12    11  5.15
#13    12  4.93
```

If you want to maintain number of rows in the dataframe add `%>% left_join(a, by = 't')` to the above answer.

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
a = tibble(x = runif(1000,0,10),
           t = rpois(1000,4)
) %>% arrange(t)
```

Comment: I think that your code is mathematically incorrect since it does not account for the ```n``` of the groups, nor the join accounts for the shift (1 is associated to the average in t=0). Even with adjustments, it's a bit clunky.Look how smooth it is on the for cycle in comparison.